# How do I check my ini file and read user input?

Tags: python, if-statement, ini, configparser

So I am trying to make an if statement saying:

```
while not exit:
    if updater['SETTINGS']['stickers'].value == "any" "demand" "rares" "robux":
        exit = True
    try:
        FindingAsset = FirstJSON['offers'][1]["userAssets"][0]['assetId']
        FindingAsset1 = FirstJSON['offers'][1]["userAssets"][1]['assetId']
        FindingAsset2 = FirstJSON['offers'][1]["userAssets"][2]['assetId']
        FindingAsset3 = FirstJSON['offers'][1]["userAssets"][3]['assetId']
        findmyasset = FirstJSON['offers'][0]["userAssets"][0]['assetId']
        findmyasset1 = FirstJSON['offers'][0]["userAssets"][1]['assetId']
        findmyasset2 = FirstJSON['offers'][0]["userAssets"][2]['assetId']
        findmyasset3 = FirstJSON['offers'][0]["userAssets"][3]['assetId']
```

And what im trying to do is check if the user put any of the things I wrote which is "any" "demand" "rares" "robux" and if its equal to any of them then make exit = True, im wondering if this is the right way to do it. It doesn't have to be equal to all of them, at least 1 of them
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `in` keyword to check if a value is in a list of values:

```
if updater['SETTINGS']['stickers'].value in ["any", "demand", "rares", "robux"]:
```

Comment: So if its equal to one of them will it still work and exit = true?

Answer (score 0):

What your current code is doing is just doing one comparison and that is with the first one `== "any"`

If you want to do an `OR` i.e. any one of them, my advice is use sets or lists

`x in {"any" , "demand" , "rares" , "robux"}` #this will work in O(1)

OR

`x in ["any" , "demand" , "rares" , "robux"]`

Your `x` is `updater['SETTINGS']['stickers'].value`

Now if `x` is any one of them this will work!

`if updater['SETTINGS']['stickers'].value in {"any" , "demand" , "rares" , "robux"}`

OR

`if updater['SETTINGS']['stickers'].value in ["any", "demand", "rares", "robux"]`

will set `exit = true` if its equal to one of them